# Differentiation between Abstraction - Encapsulation and Polymorphism - Overloading

Tags: php, oop, polymorphism, overloading, encapsulation

I am reading different articles on these terminologies but I am unable to understand actual difference between these terminologies. I need some real example e.g some code example, to understand how abstraction and encapsulation works. 
Somebody also please tell me the difference between polymorphism and overloading. Help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Hi there you may try to read this maybe it will help:

```
 Short answer: 
  They are the same. 

 Long Answer, (and yet less revealing): 


  Polymorphism is simply the ability to have many different methods (Or functions, 
 for those who are used to C-Type programs) to have the same name but act differently 
  depending on the type of parameters that were passed to the function. 

 So for example, we may have a method called punch, which accepts no parameters at 
   all, 
 and returns an integer: 

  public int punch() 
 { 
  return 3; 
} 


  We could also have a method named punch that accepts a String and returns a 
boolean. 

public boolean punch(String poorGuyGettingPunched) 
{ 
 if(poorGuyGettingPunched.equals("joe")) 
{ 
 System.out.println("sorry Joe"); 
 return true; 
 } 
 else 
   return false; 
   } 

 That is called polymorphism... And strangely enough, it is also called overloading.
```